# Suddenly incorrect fontification of newlines

Tags: font-lock, newlines

When a font style is applied to the newline character, certain styles - such as background colors - normally are extended to the end of the visual line. Suddenly this has changed for me, and the fonts make it look like the newline character is a trailing space.

[image]

What can cause this?

I am running Emacs 27.2 on Open Suse 15.1 64 bit. I recently performed a major update of packages, after the updater had been stuck for a while, so I suspect something in there might be causing the change.

Comment: This may be the `:extend` attribute on faces, new in Emacs 27 — see [the NEWS file](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/etc/NEWS.27#L469). I wonder if some package changed it to be false in an update.

Comment: @amitp This was the cause. In some cases, it was caused by me inheriting from `mode-line`, `mode-line-inactive` for highlighting separator lines / code section headline comments with custom rules. In the case of `python-cell-mode` it is because it inherits from `highlight`, which does not have the `extend` attribute. Turn your comment into an answer, then I can accept it :) The choice of making it "off by default, because everyone else does it" might not fit well with the Emacs ecosystem, but I guess it is a future investment?